# Button size dont change according to the width size

Tags: css, media-queries

I have attempted to use media query to make my website graphically nicer on the tablet/smartphone. I looked around and found a common syntax to adjust the size via the width of the media.

```
/*Media Query*/

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 720px) {

#homebutton input[type=image] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 700px;
}
}
```

Based on my understanding, if my device width is 720px and below, the homebutton size will enlarged to 700px. However, despite testing on 2 of my emulator each sizing 1024px and 480px. The homebutton for both emulators are at a height of 700px.

I have also added the most important thing which is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZLEA/). Pardon me if i made any mistake as i'm not a season-user on jsfiddle

Comment: can u pls show us your demo problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: make sure you include this meta tag in your html: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> otherwise the media query won't work. This could be your problem

Comment: That is one big button!

Comment: i'm just randomly typing any px for testing purposes only :P have no worries. My imagebutton size wont be that big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**UPDATE**
```

Check the Jsfiddle and add those CSS in your project and let me know your concern

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/jNZEL/

Here are the standard media queries used in a site:

Hope this helps you

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { ..styles go here }

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait),
screen and (max-width: 994px) { /* for tablets in portrait mode and desktops with less than 994px of horizontal browser width */ }

@media screen and (max-width: 555px),
screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { /* for desktops with less than 555px of horizontal browser width and devices with less than 480px wide (most phones in landscape orientation) */ }

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { /* anything less than 320px (primarily phones in portrait */ }
```

Use meta tag as well

Comment: If i have not mistaken, it's quite similiar to mine as shown above. I'm just trying out and testing it on a simple image before proceeding to something more difficult.

Comment: you are only using one media query or are you using media query for size greater tahn 720px? like the one which i have specified at the top

Comment: At the moment from my code above, im hoping that once the detected device does not reach beyond the maximum width, the home button size will change accordingly to 700px

Comment: is your website hosted..so we can test or some sample code....probably in jsfiddle

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle above. As for how i test my project, i have mentioned above. I develop my project in VS2012 and i run my project in a opera mobile emulator. This emulator enables me to select any width according to my preference. Regards :)

Comment: Thanks . With those basic syntax i will be able to go further into my media queries. :)

Comment: However i have a few questions.

Is it a must to have 2 or more conditions for the width of the media devices? I find it weird to see some with 2 conditions before the backets while some are just 1 condition.

Comment: One condition is enough..but in some devices to get into more precise one specifies more than 1 condition..